# Why I can't get output after I press action button?

Tags: r, shiny

My code is actually a regression model that gives the value of the desired dependent variable by taking the values ​​of several independent variables from the user. But the problem is, no output is given after setting inputs and pressing the action button. Thank you for your guidance

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Transportatin cost predcting"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(h2("input"), 
                               numericInput('distance.from.source.to.site','#Distance From Source To Site', value = "", width = NULL),
                               numericInput('distance.from..origin.to.Tehran','#Distance From Origin to Tehran', value = "", width = NULL),
                               numericInput('X.The.volume.of..moved.goods ','#The Volume of Moved Goods', value = "", width = NULL),
                               numericInput('X.percentage.of.reversibility ','#Percentage of Reversibility', value = "", width = NULL),
                               numericInput('X.Road.type','#Road type', value = "", width = NULL),
                               actionButton(inputId = "do", "calc")),
                  mainPanel(h1('First Model '),h2('Predict Leaving Cost'),h6('y=2352000+8217*Distance From Source To Site-1383*Distance From Origin to Tehran-2.325*The Volume of Moved Goods+15820*Percentage of Reversibility+421900*Road type'),h4("Output"),
                            textOutput('result'),
                            br(),br(),
                            )
                ))

server<-function(input,output,session){
 
  
  coefs <- coef(test_model_2)
  
  
  
    eventReactive(input$do,{
    calculatedvalue <- coefs[1]+coefs[2]*input$distance.from.source.to.site+coefs[3]*input$distance.from..origin.to.Tehran+coefs[4]*input$X.The.volume.of..moved.goods+coefs[5]*input$X.percentage.of.reversibility+coefs[6]*input$X.Road.type
    
  })
  
  output$result <- renderText({paste('The value is' ,calculatedvalue)})
  
 
  }
 
  
shinyApp(ui=ui,server = server)
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no return value from `eventReactive`. Also, the return value needs to be called as a reactive variable (with bracketS) inside `renderText`. However, could not test it as it's not reproducible.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Transportatin cost predcting"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(h2("input"), 
                               numericInput('distance.from.source.to.site','#Distance From Source To Site', value = "", width = NULL),
                               numericInput('distance.from..origin.to.Tehran','#Distance From Origin to Tehran', value = "", width = NULL),
                               numericInput('X.The.volume.of..moved.goods ','#The Volume of Moved Goods', value = "", width = NULL),
                               numericInput('X.percentage.of.reversibility ','#Percentage of Reversibility', value = "", width = NULL),
                               numericInput('X.Road.type','#Road type', value = "", width = NULL),
                               actionButton(inputId = "do", "calc")),
                  mainPanel(h1('First Model '),h2('Predict Leaving Cost'),h6('y=2352000+8217*Distance From Source To Site-1383*Distance From Origin to Tehran-2.325*The Volume of Moved Goods+15820*Percentage of Reversibility+421900*Road type'),h4("Output"),
                            textOutput('result'),
                            br(),br(),
                  )
                ))

server<-function(input,output,session){
  
  
  coefs <- coef(test_model_2)
  
  
  calculatedvalue <- reactiveVal()

  calculatedvalue <- eventReactive(input$do,{
    coefs[1]+coefs[2]*input$distance.from.source.to.site+coefs[3]*input$distance.from..origin.to.Tehran+coefs[4]*input$X.The.volume.of..moved.goods+coefs[5]*input$X.percentage.of.reversibility+coefs[6]*input$X.Road.type
    
  })
  
  output$result <- renderText({paste('The value is' ,calculatedvalue())})
  
  
}


shinyApp(ui=ui,server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you. now my action button works. but unfortunately, I don't get any number from coefs[1]+coefs[2]*input$distance.from.source.to.site+coefs[3]*input$distance.from..origin.to.Tehran+coefs[4]*input$X.The.volume.of..moved.goods+coefs[5]*input$X.percentage.of.reversibility+coefs[6]*input$X.Road.type .                                                                                                     how can I fix it?

Comment: Seems to be a problem in your expression inside `eventReactive`. As `test_model_2` seems to be something from your environment, I can't reproduce your problem. But what's remarkable in your code: I would recommend using more identifiable inputIds in your numericInputs, especially the blanks at the end could be disturbing. In order to make sure that the values from your numericInputs are available, use `shiny::req` before you use them.